# Big Oh of creating a BST from a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, asymptotic-complexity

I have written this method to convert a sorted array that I have, to a balanced binary search tree. I'm not sure what the big O time complexity of this method should be. Would it be O(n)?

```
Node ArrayToBST(Node arr[], int start, int end) 
{
    if (start > end) 
        return null;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Node node =arr[mid]; 
    node.left = ArrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
    node.right = ArrayToBST(arr, mid + 1, end);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Lets try some Socratic method.   What is Big O's purpose?  As in, what is its definition?  Its the measurement of the time for an algorithm to complete with a given input.  Normally measured in terms of that input n.  Right?  How many times do you touch all the elements in arr[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity will be `O(n)`. Every node is created so there will be n calls...each having O(1) runtime.

`T(n)=2T(n/2)+C` if you use masters theorem you will arrive at the same conclusion.

Master's theorem rules:-

1. If `n^(log b base a) < f(n)` then `T(n) = f(n)`
2. If `n^(log b base a) = f(n)` then `T(n) = f(n) * log n`
3. If `n^(log b base a) > f(n)` then `T(n) = n^(log b base a)`

> ```
> `n` -> input size
> `a` -> number of subproblems
> `n/b` -> size of each subproblem
> `f(n`) -> cost of non-recursive calls (Here C)
> ```

Here

```
a = 2, b = 2, f(n) = O(1)

n^(log b base a) = n = O(n)
```

Here `<` or `>` denotes polynomially smaller or larger.

Answer (score 0):

It is in O(n).
The total time is defined as T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C:

- T(n): Time taken for an array of size n
- C:  Constant (Finding middle of array and linking root to left and right subtrees take constant time)